# Is it possible to make a nested wicked wizard form?? or nested form in a nested form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, wicked-gem, cocoon-gem

i have three models associated by has_many and through, and i need to make a form for them.
the association is like, a user has many projects; a project has many tasks; a user has many tasks through projects. 
what i want to do is a user can create a project first, and also add as many as tasks (by cocoon link_to_add_association); after finishing the previous step, user can continue adding new project with many tasks, i.e the previous form step is repeated until it is finished (we will have finish button).

Comment: Have you tried it? It is definitely possible. Please show what you tried or where you are stuck. Also note cocoon has an [example-project](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo) and [wiki-page](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms) showing amongst others double nested relations.

Comment: Thanks! we tried, and it is definitely doable. :)